# Offline Mediawiki editing / syncing?

Tags: sync, wiki, mediawiki

I run a private mediawiki site for research and study, but its a catch 22 situation of I have the most time to organise it when I'm on the road and not online!

Aside from getting a 3G dongle (although I'd then waste the time on SU, or FB!) is there any way to offline-edit and then sync my mediawiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Special:Export` to 'check out' the pages you need, and use `Special:Import` to 'check in' the pages. Note that `Special:Import` requires sysop or bureaucrat (forget which) rights. You should have sysop (admin) rights considering you run it yourself.

Comment: I take it the only way to edit them then is to set up a laptop-local mediawiki instance and import on the fly so to speak?

Comment: Yes (15 characters)

Comment: Well, you could theoretically edit the XML file itself... Highly inefficient though.